# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'email' of undefined" when trying to use EmailComposer

Tags: android, cordova-3

I am building an app in Cordova 3.1, and trying to generate emails using the email composer plugin found here:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

However, when I test the email button, I get the following error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'email' of undefined**

It happens on the third line here:

```
function sendEmail(message){
        subject = 'Optum Whole Health Tracker';
        window.plugin.email.open({
            subject: subject,
            body: message
            });
    }
```

I have tried removing and re-adding the plugin, but it looks like it isn't getting called for some reason.

Comment: This code is not enough post more code

Comment: What code or files are you looking for specifically? I am more than willing, but I don't want to just post the entire project

Answer (score -1):

This works for adding subject and body, I haven't been able to get the file attachment working. This is for an email with html body. For text body change the true to false.

```
function sendemail(){
    window.plugin.email.open({
        attachments: [],
        subject: 'What ever',
        body:    'Put body in here',
        isHtml:  true
    });
}
```